# Ext GWT 2.2.1 and GWT 2.1.1

Tags: gxt

I am trying to use `Ext GWT 2.0` to build an AJAX based web application. I ran into a snag while trying to use the `GXT BeanModel` classes.

In essence I am attempting to use the BeanModelMarker along the @BEAN annotation to define a `BeanModel` object.

At compilation time, I get the following error:

> [ERROR] Class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BeanModelLookup not found.
>        [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.NotFoundException: [JAVA BEAN CLASS NAME HERE]
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.TypeOracle.getType(TypeOracle.java:534)
>        [java]     at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.getMarkerBean(BeanModelGenerator.java:188)
>        [java]     at com.extjs.gxt.ui.rebind.core.BeanModelGenerator.generate(BeanModelGenerator.java:55)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGenerator(StandardGeneratorContext.java:427)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:39)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.tryRebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:115)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:58)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:161)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:150)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile$DistillerRebindPermutationOracle.getAllPossibleRebindAnswers(Precompile.java:345)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.doFindAdditionalTypesUsingRebinds(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:106)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.process(AbstractCompiler.java:254)
>        [java]     at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:175)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:288)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler$Sandbox$CompilerImpl.access$400(AbstractCompiler.java:145)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.AbstractCompiler.compile(AbstractCompiler.java:632)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.BasicWebModeCompiler.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(BasicWebModeCompiler.java:124)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jdt.WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.getCompilationUnitDeclarations(WebModeCompilerFrontEnd.java:54)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaToJavaScriptCompiler.java:484)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.JavaScriptCompiler.precompile(JavaScriptCompiler.java:32)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:545)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Precompile.precompile(Precompile.java:466)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:205)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:177)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:149)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:87)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:81)
>        [java]     at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:156)
>        [java]    [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:[FILE PATH]/gxt.jar!/com/extjs/gxt/ui/client/data/BeanModelLookup.java'
>        [java]       [ERROR] Line 34:  Failed to resolve 'com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.data.BeanModelLookup' via deferred binding
>        [java]    [ERROR] Cannot proceed due to previous errors

Answer (score 0):

Need to add source path to gwt.xml